# How to let the div grows based on Jquery sortable grid's height?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am new to Jquery, and trying to follow an example on [JqueryUI Display Grid](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid), and putting it on a div.

So the code basically looks like this:

JS code:

```
$('#demoList').sortable();
$('#demoList').disableSelection();
var contentHeight  = $('#demoContent').height() + 200; 
$('#demoContent').animate({height: contentHeight});
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="demoContent">
        <ul id="demoList">
            <!-- <li> items generated based on the items from MySql -->
            <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="2.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="3.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="4.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><img src="5.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></li>
            <!-- There could be more than 5 images... -->
        </ul>
</div>
```

Currently I could only add a fixed 200px to my `contentHeight`, but I need it to be more specify based on the rows of items that I could have generated from the database. My question is, how is it possible to let `demoContent` "grow" its height based on the number of rows of images there could be (say if each row could contain up to 5 images)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if ive understand you correctly this has nothing to do with javascript :) you just need a clearer and remove this height() stuff.

```
    <div id="demoContent">
           <ul id="demoList">
                    <!-- items -->
           </ul>
           <div style="clear: both;"> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: antpaw: Yup, you've fixed my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the [`slideDown`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown#speedcallback) animation, like this:

```
$('#demoContent').slideDown();
```

If you want to get the height of the grid, call `$('#demoList').height()`.

Comment: SLaks: I changed to slideDown animation and tried adding $('#demoList').height(); but the return value for this height is 0px. Am I missing something?